# Getting length in bytes of FileInputStream

Tags: android, media-player, inputstream, android-mediaplayer, file-descriptor

I'm trying to use the `setDataSource(FileDescriptor fd, long offset, long length)` method from the Mediaplayer. I got the FileDescriptor from an FileInputStream. If the length parameter is `the length in bytes of the data to be played` then how would I go from FileInputStream to length.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`setDataSource(FileDescriptor fd)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource%28java.io.FileDescriptor%29).